# adding to a secondary multi dimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am retrieving data from a database. The final results i am looking for is a multidimensional array with the key being an integer and the value being another array.

The data being held is questions and answer to help my study for an exam, (NOT on PHP!)

I would like the data to be like below:

```
100 = {question,answer}
101 = {question,answer}
102 = {question,answer}
103 = {question,answer}
etc . . .
```

I then will be able to call any question/answer i want.

My problem lies below,

The line

```
$tempArray[$row['question']] = $row['answer'];
```

works as expected, i have my question and answer

but, the line

```
$this->categoryArray[$count] = $tempArray;
```

does not, $count is never used as expected, when i check it with

```
print_r(array_keys($this->categoryArray)
```

i get 0,1,2 - instead of 100,101,102

As always Mr Internet, your help is always appreciated.

Full code below

```
$count = 100;
while($row = $stmt ->fetch())
{
   $tempArray[$row['question']] = $row['answer'];
   $this->categoryArray[$count] = $tempArray;
   $count++;
   unset($tempArray);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need `array_combine`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this close to what you are looking for?

```
$count = 100;


$qa = array(
    "question1" => "answer1",
    "question2" => "answer2",
    "question3" => "answer3"
    );

$category_array = array();

foreach($qa as $question=>$answer) {
    $category_array[$count] = array($question=>$answer);
    $count++;
}

print_r($category_array);
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [100] => Array
        (
            [question1] => answer1
        )

    [101] => Array
        (
            [question2] => answer2
        )

    [102] => Array
        (
            [question3] => answer3
        )

)
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for taking the time to respond, turns out my code does work, and obviously so does yours. 

The problem i found was that i was shuffling the questions as soon as the array was created with shuffle($this->categoryArray)

And ofcourse

Note: This function assigns new keys to the elements in array. It will remove any existing keys that may have been assigned, rather than just reordering the keys.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are using it inside the class, I am right? Is $count inside the function or out of?

If yes, please also use $this->count instead of $count...